# PHP- Save Access Tokens for Tumblr API

Tags: php, api, tumblr, access-token

So I've been up all night trying to figure this out (literally). But Im stumped. What I want to do is, simply, to save access tokens for future use and to allow users to not have to "Allow" the app each time. When I use the access tokens in "done.php" that I stored and retrieved, the "GET" action works but the "POST" doesnt.

**addblogs.php (This script, ran right after registration, snags the access tokens and stores them... right now it isn't salted, but it will be)**

```
include('functions.php');
require_once('tumblroauth/tumblroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');
session_start();
sec_session_start();
$tumblrblog = $_SESSION['tumblrblog'];

$connection = new TumblrOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

$access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

unset($_SESSION['oauth_token']);
unset($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

if (200 == $connection->http_code) {
$at = implode(",",$access_token);

$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tumblogs (tumblrblog, access_token) VALUES ( ?, ?)");
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('ss', $tumblrblog, $at); 
   $insert_stmt->execute();
print_r ($access_token);

} else {
  header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}
```

**done.php (Retreive and Use the saved access tokens)**

```
include('functions.php');
session_start();
sec_session_start();
require_once('tumblroauth/tumblroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');
$tumblrblog = $_SESSION['tumblrblog'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT access_token FROM `tumblogs` WHERE tumblrblog=? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $tumblrblog);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($at);
$stmt->fetch();

$access_token = explode(",", $at);

$connection = new TumblrOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['0'], $access_token['1']);

print_r($access_token['0']);

$hostname = "$tumblrblog.tumblr.com";
$connection = new TumblrOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['0'], $access_token['1']);
$userinfo = $connection->get('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info');
print_r($userinfo);
$pic_path = "dir/$tumblrblog/good/icon.png";
$pic = file_get_contents($pic_path);
$connection->post('api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/$hostname/post', array('type' => 'text', 'body' => 'this is a test of Tumbloadr v2'));
```

Thank you all for taking a look!

Brandon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In done.php I would verify that you're also retrieving the correct access token secret by printing `$access_token[1]` as well. Also, I would remove one of the $connections, theres no need to do it twice. To be a bit more dynamic, you can get the $hostname using this 
    `$hostname = parse_url($blog->url,PHP_URL_HOST);`
This clearly isn't a fix, but hopefully it helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Why not serialize accessToken before inserting to database? I think it will be the correct way to store tokens in database. You can never know if the token contains "," chars then would your explode destroy the whole access token.

When I store tokens for Dropbox I had to serialize and unserialize when using it.